# How to impersonate user using Go Google SDK?

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-admin-sdk, google-reporting-api

I have a user which I use to query the [Reports API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/get-start/getting-started). I generated the token and read the credentials using the [`google.ConfigFromJSON`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/oauth2/google#ConfigFromJSON) method.

Although, now I need to do the same, but instead of a user, I need to use a service account. And accordingly to the documentation, I need to impersonate a user as it's not possible to call the API using a service account (correct me if I'm wrong).

This is what I did to impersonate the user:

```golang
impersonatedOption := option.ImpersonateCredentials("user@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com")
credsOption := option.WithCredentialsFile("cert.json")
scopesOption := option.WithScopes(admin.AdminReportsAuditReadonlyScope)

httpClient, _, err := transport.NewHTTPClient(ctx,  scopesOption, credsOption, impersonatedOption)

srv, err := admin.NewService(ctx, option.WithHTTPClient(httpClient))
```

But no success:

```
Get "https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/reports/v1/activity/users/all/applications/login?alt=json&eventName=account_disabled_spamming&prettyPrint=false": impersonate: status code 403:
```

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

The service account is configured as a SuperAdmin and should have all permissions.

Comment: It looks like your subject that the service account is impersonating is a service account and not a user or admin. Also the service account used needs to have Domain Wide Delegation to be able to impersonate a user in the domain.

Comment: Hi Aerials, I tried with a user as well (email@domain.com) and the service account has Domain Wide Delegation enabled (with the `AdminReportsAuditReadonlyScope` role on it). Although in the Domain Wide Delegation settings the ID refers to the service account, is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just needed to load the cert, and set the `Subject` to be able to impersonate the user:

```golang
    config, err := google.JWTConfigFromJSON(b, scope...)
    config.Subject = "impersonated_user@email.com"
```

Comment: would you mind to share the full code for this. I'm stuck can't find how to achive this

Comment: Sure, but there's not much difference from the code above: https://play.golang.org/p/MsPMZLr9EoU

Comment: What if I'm using environment provided account instead of exact json file? I mean when running on GCP you should not generate json keys.